# sending empty files to server React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, file-upload, multer

I am trying to send JSON files to Server using NodeJS with multer and i am able to send files but the files are empty.

I am using React-native-File-System to loop through all the files present in the folder

I am not getting any errors and the file upload logs is also showing as UPLOAD COMPLETED but the files are empty

I have tried to send it with form-data but still no luck

```
        var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

        var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/toBeSynced';

        RNFS.readDir(path)
            .then((success) => {
                success.forEach(function (element) {
                    var fileName = element.name
                    var filePath = element.path
                    const options = {
                        url: 'http://192.168.1.15:3333/SurveyJsonFiles/GetFiles',
                        path: filePath,
                        name: fileName,
                        field: 'files',
                        method: 'POST',
                        type: 'multipart',
                        headers: {
                            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                        },
                        //Below are options only supported on Android
                        notification: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }

                    Upload.startUpload(options).then((uploadId) => {
                        console.log('Upload started')
                        Upload.addListener('progress', uploadId, (data) => {
                            console.log(`Progress: ${data.progress}%`)
                        })
                        Upload.addListener('error', uploadId, (data) => {
                            console.log(`Error: ${data.error}%`)
                        })
                        Upload.addListener('cancelled', uploadId, (data) => {
                            console.log(`cancelled: ${data.error}%`)
                        })
                        Upload.addListener('completed', uploadId, (data) => {
                            // data includes responseCode: number and responseBody: Object
                            console.log('Completed!')
                        })
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.log('Upload error!', err)
                    })


                });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.message);
            });
    }
```

Comment: How do the logs look like?

Comment: the logs are not showing any error only "progress 100% upload completed" but the files are empty

Comment: Any git repo that can be used to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no. but there is an example which i have referred (https://github.com/Vydia/ReactNativeBackgroundUploadExample)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was on the server side as nodemon was restarting  server when it was getting new file

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('files', {
    uri: filePath,
    type: 'multipart/form-data',
    name: fileName,
    });

const config = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
         },
    body: data,
    };

fetch(uploadUrl, config)
.then((checkStatusAndGetJSONResponse) => {
    console.log(checkStatusAndGetJSONResponse);
    }).catch((err) => {
       console.log(err)
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path is not an absolute file item path.
if you have lots of file, add this code

```
var files = [
  {
    name: 'test1',
    filename: 'test1.w4a',
    filepath: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test1.w4a',
    filetype: 'audio/x-m4a'
  }, {
    name: 'test2',
    filename: 'test2.w4a',
    filepath: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test2.w4a',
    filetype: 'audio/x-m4a'
  }
];
```

if you have only one file, add like this.

```
 var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/toBeSynced/test.txt';
```

or

```
 var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.txt';
```

You can look at these.
https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#examples

https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#constants

Comment: are you sure selected files? can you write log about selected files?

Comment: The files are getting selected they are also being sent to the server but the files contain no data as they contain data on mobile

Comment: Check your files is empty or no?

Comment: I have checked, the files have data.

Comment: logs for upload UPLOAD HAS BEGUN! JobId: 1
 UPLOAD IS 1% DONE!
 UPLOAD IS 100% DONE! FILES UPLOADED!

Comment: i didn't, even if the upload is showing completed the files are still empty